# Notepad++ RegEx Only change last line in specific file

Tags: notepad++, regex

The problem is i want to comment out a specific string in some files.

In most of them it looks like this

```
countries = {"GER","NZG",}
```

Replacing this is trivial.
However there are some exception in which the string looks like this:

```
    countries = {
         "GER","NZG",
    }
```

I replaced the first line in the first run through by replacing "countries" with "--countries".

Now I found the next row with

```
^([\s][\"][A-Z]{3}[\"])
```

and Replaced it by

```
-- \1
```

Now my files look like this

```
 --countries = {
 --      "GER","NZG",
   }
```

I know this is not very efficent.

As you can see, I need to comment out the last "}". It is the last "}" in every file. But there are other single "}" in one rows.

These are lua files so maybe block commenting would be better. Still i don't know how to find the last "}" in the file.

Would be nice if someone could help me with that.

Comment: Why is this tagged for microsoft-excel?

Comment: Sorry, i just added the recommended Tags. 
I thought this is more of a RegEx problem so ppl who know it from other programms might know an answare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+\h*=\h*\{)([^}]+)(\})`
- Replace with: `--$1\n--\t$2\n--$3`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # begining of line
  (             # start group 1
    \w+         # 1 or more word character
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    =           # equal sign
    \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \{          # opening curly brace
  )             # end group 1
  (             # start group 2
    [^}]+       # 1 or more non closing brace
  )             # end group 2
  (\})          # group 3, a closing curly brace
```

**Replacement:**

```
--$1            # 2 hyphens and content of group 1
\n              # linefeed, you may use \r\n for Windows
--\t$2          # 2 hyphens, a tabulation, content of group 3
\n              # linefeed
--$3            # 2 hyphens and content of group 3
```

**Result for given example:**

```
--countries = {
--  "GER","NZG",
--}
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Wow very nice. Okay this worked semi. It also found other strings which i solved by adding \bcountries\b to the first group instead of \w+.
I also changed the replace with --[[ $1 \n \t$2 \n $3 ]] (for block commenting)
Also thank you for the explanation what all those expressions mean.
My last try to find those strings looked like this xD
^([\s]?\bcountries\b[\s][\=][\s][\{][\s]?){1} ([\s]?([\"][A-Z]{3}[\"])+[\s]?[\,]*)+([\s]?[\}])

Comment: @Binary: You don't need to use character class for a single character, `[\s]` is better written `\s`, `[\"]` ==> `"`, `[\=]` ==> `=`, `{1}` is superfluous as `\b` between `\s` and `countries` If you want to only match `countries`, use `(\bcountries\h*=\h*\{)([^}]+)(\})`